# Angular 5 npm build crashing (Rebalance Allocation failed - process out of memory)

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, build

I have build an Angular 5 web portal.

When running the command on my local mac it is successful.

```
npm run build
```

However, when running the same on linux server it crashes with an error:

```
Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [ng]
 2: 0x121a7ac [ng]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [ng]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [ng]
 5: 0xaea73b [ng]
 6: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::Evacuate() [ng]
 7: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [ng]
 8: v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [ng]
 9: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng]
10: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [ng]
11: v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [ng]
12: v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInTargetSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [ng]
13: 0x18aab070463d
```

CPU configuration of server:

```
description: CPU
product: Virtual CPU 714389bda930
vendor: Intel Corp.
physical id: 400
bus info: cpu@0
version: pc-i440fx-2.10
slot: CPU 0
size: 2GHz
capacity: 2GHz
width: 64 bits
```

Memory:

```
description: System Memory
physical id: 1000
size: 1GiB
capacity: 1GiB
```

Thanks in advance.

Is the limitation of memory the reason or could there be anything else?

Answer (score -1):

I do like that, It worked for me 
Go to your node module folder bin eg: D:...\node_modules\.bin
Use notepad++ then Find in Files "--max-old-space-size=10240" replate with "--max-old-space-size=1024000" (replate all inside files)
You can found the value --max-old-space-size by open any file in .bin folder
eg file "acorn"
[image: change limit memory]

Comment: In my case, i dont have this line in my bin folder.